# How to make puppy defecate and urinate in the same place?

Tags: toilet-training

I have a 2 month old Cocker Spaniel puppy and he urinates in designated spot correctly but when it comes to stool he always misses it and makes a mess and keeps stepping in it.

How can I train him to do defecate in the same spot as urine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a puppy once that we trained using training pads. She generally got on the pad before going, but she did get to the point where once she could smell the pad, she would go. This meant she would urinate and defecate right next to the pad. Once she began doing that, we just removed the pads and she would always go outside to do her business.

You may need to increase the intensity of however you choose to train your pet until he understands that he needs to hit the right mark.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, since I posted the question I've been patient with him and he is getting better. Now he defecates on the edge of the potty training pad which is good enough for now.